# loading of Python program in Visual Studio frequently fails first or second time

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

Wondering if others are experiencing this...I've got a fresh install of VS 2015 with PTVS 2016 and I almost always have to open the .sln file twice since the first time it opens the project will fail to load (this failure is displayed in the solution explorer in VS).  Perhaps there is a quick fix but I didn't see anything during a cursory search on the web.  Maybe there is a setting somewhere that I've got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here (VS Enterprise 2015 Update 3, PTVS 2.2.50113.00): I have a solution with many different project types (most of them C#) and ONE Python project. Opening the solution loads ALL projects but the one-and-only Python project. The Solution Explorer entry for that project displays an error message like "opening the project requires manual input). Right-clicking on the (not-yet-loaded) project and choosing the "Load Project" menu item then successfully loads the project.

Somewhat annoying.

Thanks for help